# Combining rows where values in df1 correspond to values in df2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have two large data sets that look like similar to the following

DataFrame `df1`:

```
P    Y    p_start   p_stop
p1   y1      7         9
p2   y2      6         7
p3   y3      12        14
```

DataFrame `df2`:

```
T    t_start    t_stop 
t1      5          10
t2      11         15
```

I would like to check if `P` lies within the region `T`. If so I need to append that row of `df1` to the corresponding row of `df2`. If there are **multiple matches I need to add them both to the same row**. Ideally I would like my output to look like this:

Desired output:

```
T   t_start  t_stop   P_1   Y_1   p_start_1   p_stop_1  P_2  Y_2  p_start_2  p_stop_2
t1     5       10      p1   y1       7           9       p2   y2      6         7
t2     11      15      p3   y3      12          14
```

my logic is something like the following but I am not sure how to actually make it work

```
for line in df1:
    if df1['p_start'] >= df2['t_start'] & df1['p_end'] <= df2['t_end']:
        df2 = df1.append(['X', 'Y', 'p_start', 'p_stop'])
```

I am using column names since I have many more columns that I do not need to append. I omitted them from the sample data for simplicity. I'm more worried about finding the match and appending to the correct row of df2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
# STEP 1
df3 = df2.assign(key=1).merge(df1.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', 1)

# STEP 2
df3 = df3[df3['t_start'].lt(df3['p_start']) & df3['t_stop'].gt(df3['p_stop'])]

# STEP 3
df3 = df3.melt(['T', 't_start', 't_stop'])

# STEP 4
df3['variable'] += '_' + df3.groupby(['T', 't_start', 't_stop', 'variable']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
    
# STEP 5
df3 = (
    df3.set_index(['T', 't_start', 't_stop', 'variable'])
    .unstack().droplevel(0, 1).rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
)
```

Explanation/Steps:

STEP 1: Use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to merge the two dataframes on the common temporary column `key`. By using merge we create all possible combinations of the rows in two dataframe so that we can filter the rows in `STEP 2` which satisfies our condition.

```
# STEP 1
    T  t_start  t_stop   P   Y  p_start  p_stop
0  t1        5      10  p1  y1        7       9
1  t1        5      10  p2  y2        6       7
2  t1        5      10  p3  y3       12      14
3  t2       11      15  p1  y1        7       9
4  t2       11      15  p2  y2        6       7
5  t2       11      15  p3  y3       12      14
```

STEP 2: Filter the rows in merged dataframe `df3` such that `p_start` is greater that `t_start` and `t_stop` is greater that `p_stop`, i.e, `p_start` and `p_stop` lies in the region `t_start` and `t_stop`.

```
# STEP 2
    T  t_start  t_stop   P   Y  p_start  p_stop
0  t1        5      10  p1  y1        7       9
1  t1        5      10  p2  y2        6       7
5  t2       11      15  p3  y3       12      14
```

STEP 3: Use [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to melt the dataframe `i.e` to convert the columns `P, Y, p_start, p_stop` into rows.

```
# STEP 3
     T  t_start  t_stop variable value
0   t1        5      10        P    p1
1   t1        5      10        P    p2
2   t2       11      15        P    p3
3   t1        5      10        Y    y1
4   t1        5      10        Y    y2
5   t2       11      15        Y    y3
6   t1        5      10  p_start     7
7   t1        5      10  p_start     6
8   t2       11      15  p_start    12
9   t1        5      10   p_stop     9
10  t1        5      10   p_stop     7
11  t2       11      15   p_stop    14
```

STEP 4: Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on the given columns and use the transformation `cumcount` and add this to the column `variable` to add a sequential counter to the column `variable`.

```
# STEP 4
     T  t_start  t_stop   variable value
0   t1        5      10        P_1    p1
1   t1        5      10        P_2    p2
2   t2       11      15        P_1    p3
3   t1        5      10        Y_1    y1
4   t1        5      10        Y_2    y2
5   t2       11      15        Y_1    y3
6   t1        5      10  p_start_1     7
7   t1        5      10  p_start_2     6
8   t2       11      15  p_start_1    12
9   t1        5      10   p_stop_1     9
10  t1        5      10   p_stop_2     7
11  t2       11      15   p_stop_1    14
```

STEP 5: Use `set_index` along with [`DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to unstack the dataframe and pivot the items in the `variable` column as separate individual columns.

```
# STEP 5
    T  t_start  t_stop P_1  P_2 Y_1  Y_2 p_start_1 p_start_2 p_stop_1 p_stop_2
0  t1        5      10  p1   p2  y1   y2         7         6        9        7
1  t2       11      15  p3  NaN  y3  NaN        12       NaN       14      NaN
```

STEP 6: OPTIONAL step if you want to `reorder` the columns in the dataframe.

```
# OPTIONAL for reordering columns
def sort_fx(col):
    grp, seq = re.search(
        r'(.*?)_(\d+)', col.lower()).groups()
    return seq + '1' if grp == 'start' else seq + '2' if grp == 'stop' else seq

df3 = df3.reindex(df3.columns[:3].tolist() + sorted(df3.columns[3:], key=sort_fx), axis=1)

# STEP 6
    T  t_start  t_stop P_1 Y_1 p_start_1 p_stop_1  P_2  Y_2 p_start_2 p_stop_2
0  t1        5      10  p1  y1         7        9   p2   y2         6        7
1  t2       11      15  p3  y3        12       14  NaN  NaN       NaN      NaN
```

Comment: @keenan Does this answered you question?